# Unable to refer to genesis.json file from terminal on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, polygon

I'm trying to run a command to initialize a node validator however my GCP ubuntu vm is having a hard time referring to the genesis.json file. Here is the command:

```sh
sudo docker run 0xpolygon/polygon-edge \
server \
  --data-dir ./data-dir \
  --chain /home/ubuntu/genesis.json \
  --libp2p 0.0.0.0:1478 \
  --nat [IP-ADDRESS] \
  --seal
```

When I run this it spits out this error:
Error: open /home/ubuntu/genesis.json: no such file or directory

I've triple checked the path an it's correct.

Comment: When you refer to the `genesis.json` file, you're referring to the path **in** the container **not** the host file-system. To reference the host's file system in the container, you need to mount it, e.g. `docker run --volume=/path/to/genesis.json:/home/ubuntu/genesis,json ...` will mount the file in the host's (!) `/path/to/genesis.json` in the container's `/home/ubuntu/genesis.json`. You generally don't want to `sudo docker`.

Comment: @DazWilkin I tried adding the --volume flag but got the same error:

`sudo docker run --volume=/home/cormachayden/genesis.json 0xpolygon/polygon-edge server --data-dir ./data-dir --chain /home/cormachayden/genesis.json --libp2p 0.0.0.0:1478 --nat IP-ADDRESS --seal`

Is there a better way other than sudo docker run to run the framework command? 

(it's `polygon-edge`)

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `polygon-edge` so I can't answer that. Your volume flag is incorrect. You need `--volume=${HOST}:${CONT}` so you need to map your host's `genesis.json` to wherever the container expects to find it. In your question the container's `--chain` flag appears to be the container reference

Comment: See Docker [post installation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)

Answer (score 1):

Got it working thanks to @DazWilkin's comment by attaching the genesis file as a volume

```
sudo docker run --volume=/home/ubuntu/genesis.json:/home/ubuntu/genesis.json 0xpolygon/polygon-edge server --data-dir ./data-dir --chain /home/ubuntu/genesis.json --libp2p 0.0.0.0:1478 --nat IP-ADDRESS --seal
```